# JQuery Ajax Post cannot send data (json) to express.js server

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb, jsonp

I am a newbie on Node.js. What I want to do here is to send some data in json format, from client side javascript to express.js server. Once I can do this, I will use those parameters that have been sent to the server to further retrieve information from MongoDB. The client side code is really simple, with a click event:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8020/1',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: JSON.stringify({name: "test"}),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data){
                alert("success");
                alert(data);
            }
    });
```

At the server side, the code looks like this:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var cons = require('consolidate'),
        MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        Server = require('mongodb').Server; 

    var mongoclient = new MongoClient (new Server('localhost', 27017,
                            {'native_parser' : true}));
    var db=mongoclient.db('test');

    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


    app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
      next();
     });

    app.get('/1', function (req, res) {
        db.collection('test').findOne({}, function (err, doc){
           console.log(doc);
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
        var x = req.body.name;
        console.log(x);
        res.send({});
    });


    app.post('/1', function (req, res){

           db.collection('test').findOne({}, function (err, doc){
               console.log(doc);
            });

           console.log(req.body);
    });

    mongoclient.open(function (err, mongoclient) {

        if (err) throw err;
        app.listen(8020);
        console.log("listening on port 8020");
    });
```

When I make the client side ajax call, it seems that the server-side code successfully returns an item in my mongoDB database, but it fails to capture the data, which is {name : "test"} in this case. Below is the output from the server-side console when the click event is triggered:

```
{}
undefined
{ _id: 5522f3368d21ba45c6263402, apple: 'juice' }
```

Any one has any idea on this? Is this something related to cross domain issue? Thank you very much!

Comment: Not nearly enough information given for this to be a proper question. Suggest studying some ajax tutorials and then providing more specific code related problems

Comment: it isn't possible to POST with jsonp datatype.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're sending `jsonp` as your dataType. I'm guessing jQuery performs some magic to create a `jsonp` request for you. Are you sure you need to do this?
2. You're not responding from your `POST` route. This will make requests hang indefinitely. You have to respond:

   ```
   app.post('/1', function (req, res){

          db.collection('test').findOne({}, function (err, doc){
              console.log(doc);
              res.send(doc); // respond!
          });

          console.log(req.body);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

first of all send the data as JSON not as string

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '/1',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {name: "test"},
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data){
               alert("success");
               alert(data);
        }
});
```

on the sever

```
app.post('/1', function(req, res) {
  var body = req.body;

  console.log(body)
  res.send(body)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, if I format the url as '/1', I get an error message of "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". I am thinking if it is because I don't have a real web server installed on my windows PC, and google chrome direct me to a local file location through this url. If I add "localhost:8020" before "/1", I get cross-domain problem. Any idea on that? Thanks.